# Cannot create custom config entity fails because ID is blank

Tags: 8, entities

I have created the following custom config entity. When I try to create a new one, I get the following error:

```
Drupal\Core\Entity\EntityMalformedException: The entity does not have an ID. in Drupal\Core\Config\Entity\ConfigEntityStorage->save() (line 248 of core/lib/Drupal/Core/Config/Entity/ConfigEntityStorage.php).
Drupal\Core\Entity\Entity->save() (Line: 637)
Drupal\Core\Config\Entity\ConfigEntityBase->save() (Line: 151)
```

My understanding is that the entity system will create an ID for this entity, but it doesn't seem to be working in my case. I'm struggling to figure out what I need to change to get this work:

```
<?php

namespace Drupal\example\Entity;

use Drupal\Core\Config\Entity\ConfigEntityBase;
use Drupal\example\Entity\ExampleConfigInterface;

/**
 * Defines the ExampleConfig entity.
 *
 * ExampleConfig config entities define a configuration for a specific
 * entity/bundle. Per entity settings are then saved as ExampleContent
 * entities.
 *
 * @ConfigEntityType(
 *   id = "example_config",
 *   label = @Translation("Example configuration"),
 *   fieldable = FALSE,
 *   handlers = {
 *     "list_builder" = "Drupal\example\ExampleConfigListBuilder",
 *     "form" = {
 *       "add" = "Drupal\example\Form\ExampleConfigForm",
 *       "edit" = "Drupal\example\Form\ExampleConfigForm",
 *       "delete" = "Drupal\example\Form\ExampleDeleteForm",
 *     }
 *   },
 *   config_prefix = "example",
 *   admin_permission = "administer site configuration",
 *   entity_keys = {
 *     "id" = "id",
 *     "example_entity_type" = "example_entity_type",
 *     "example_bundle" = "example_bundle",
 *   },
 *   links = {
 *     "edit-form" = "/admin/config/content/example/{example_config}",
 *     "delete-form" = "/admin/config/content/example/{example_config}/delete",
 *   }
 * )
 */
class ExampleConfig extends ConfigEntityBase implements ExampleConfigInterface {

  /**
   * The ID of the block.
   *
   * @var string
   */
  protected $id;

  protected $exampleEntityType;
  protected $exampleBundle;
  protected $exampleExpiry;
  protected $exampleDefaultStatus;

  /**
   * Get the bundle
   */
  public function getExampleBundle() {
    return $this->exampleBundle;
  }

  /**
   * Get the entity type.
   */
  public function getExampleEntityType() {
    return $this->exampleEntityType;
  }

  /**
   * Get the expiry time for this configuration.
   */
  public function getExampleExpiry() {
    if (!$this->exampleExpiry) {
      return example_expiry_default();
    }
    return $this->exampleExpiry;
  }

  /**
   * Get status for this configuration.
   */
  public function getExampleStatus() {
    return $this->exampleDefaultStatus;
  }

}
```

I have ended up prefixing all the custom properties to try to make sure I wasn't overriding something on accident. Even when the custom entity is blank, it still won't add.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> My understanding is that the entity system will create an ID for this entity, but it doesn't seem to be working in my case. I'm struggling to figure out what I need to change to get this work:

That understanding is wrong. Config entities have machine names as ID's, you have to provide that. Most UI's generate one from the label, but that's form/UI code, the API has no such thing.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, Berdir is right.

While creating new entity programatically, need to provide **ID[machine name of entity]**.

You can pass any random unique string to id or time.

E.g:

```
$entity = example_config::create(
               [
                 'label' => 'Example Entity',
                 'id' => time(),
                 'status' => true,
                 'created' => time()
               ]
         );
 $entity->save();
```

Comment: Awesome, thank you for the example! I ended up calling some id functionality from my form, but this is good to know as well.